# DataGrip - Disable code highlighting

Tags: jetbrains-ide, datagrip

[image]

Is it possible to disable this purple line syntax highlighting feature of DataGrip? All my code is being surrounded by those lines and i couldn't find the right option at settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the setting you need, friend.
[image]